# Why can't I make an include in this query?

Tags: graphql, sequelize.js, include

I'm trying to do this query and I don't understand why it doesn't work. Any idea?

```
codeMappingsScheduleACD = await db.codeMappings.findAll({
    where: { Label: codeLabel },
    include: [{
        model: db.scheduleTypes,
        required: true,
        where: { 
            Description: scheduleType
        }
    }]
})
```

The idea is simple. I need find the code labels that match the schedule type.
I have a two dropdowns: one with codeLabels, which I need to find in codeMappings table, and one with scheduleType, which I need to find in schedulesTypes table.
The first part works. I can find a specific codeLabel but the include doesn't work. I can't do the join or find or make the correct include.

Can someone help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I cleaned up the code for readability, but noticed (and removed) an extra closing `}` brace. I presume this was a typo in the sample here, not your original code? As for your issue, what errors are you seeing or what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Show the error text and model definitions and their associations

Comment: I found the solution. I don't associate the tables. Its working now. Thanks.